# how to retrieve and inject sections from and to JSON

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, shapeless

If I have an incoming JSON of following structure

```
[
   {
      "personId" : 12,
      "name": "John Doe",
      "age": 48,
      "birthdate": "12/1/1954",
      "relationships": [
           {
              "relationType":"parentOf",
              "value" : "Johnny walker"
          },
          {
             "relationType":"sonOf",
             "value" : "Charles Smith"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
        "personId" : 13,
       "name": "Merry Christmas",
       "age": 28,
       "birthdate": "12/1/1985",
       "relationships": [
            {
              "relationType":"sisteOf",
             "value" : "Will Smith"
           },
           {
             "relationType":"cousinOf",
             "value" : "Brad Pitt"
          }
       ]
   }
]
```

And requirement is that for each `Person` record controller will have to carve out `relationships` array and store each record from it in a separate `relationship` table with `personId` association while persisting this incoming JSON.

And subsequently when querying these `persons` records system will have to lookup `relationships` for each `person` from `relationships` table and inject them to form the same above looking JSON to give back to UI for rendering.

What's the best efficient way to perform this "carve out" and later "inject" operations using Play framework in Scala? (using Slick in persistent layer APIs) I have looked at [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaJsonTransformers) JSON transformation link and `json.pickBranch` in there but not quite sure if that'll be fully applicable here for "carve out" and "inject" use cases for preparing JSON shown in the example. are there any elegant ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One way, which is pretty straightforward, is to use `case` classes along with Play `Json` inceptions

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json

case class Relationship(relationType: String, value: String)

object Relationship {

  implicit val RelationshipFormatter = Json.format[Relationship]

}

case class Person(personId: String, name: String, age: Int, birthdate: String, relationships: Seq[Relationship]) {

  def withRelationships(relationship: Seq[Relationship]) = copy(relationships = relationships ++ relationship)

}

object Person {

  implicit val PersonFormatter = Json.format[Person]

}
```

Now you can convert a json value to `Person` by using the following code, provided that `jsValue` is a json value of type `JsValue` (which in play controllers you can get by `request.body.asJson`):

```
Json.fromJson[Person](jsValue)
```

In Play controllers, you can

For converting a `Person` to json you can use the following code provided that `person` is a value of type `Person` in your context:

```
Json.toJson(person)
```

The only remaining thing is your Slick schemas which is pretty straight forward.

One option is to use a simple schema for `Person`, without relations and one schema for `Relation` with a foreign key to `Person` table. Then you need to find all relations associated with a specific `Person`, namely `person` and then append them to that `person` by calling the `withRelationships` method which gives you a new `Person` which you can serve as json:

```
val person = ....      // find person
val relations = ....   // find relationships associated with this person
val json = Json.toJson(person.withRelationships(relations))
```